Issues with Data Insertion in Next.js Client Component: Seeking Assistance with Vercel PostgreSQL Integration
I'm currently developing a website using Next.js 14, React.js, and Vercel PostgreSQL. Users can create and edit content on the site.
I've successfully implemented a list page to display the contents, and it's working fine with server-side rendering. I've used the following code to create the list, and it's functioning as expected:
import React from "react";
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";
import PostTable from "./PostsTable";

const PostList = async () => {
  const { rows } =
    await sql`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS RN, TITLE, CONTENT, USER_NAME AS NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, EMAIL, PASSWORD, TO_CHAR(CREATED_AT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS CREATEDAT FROM POSTS WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC`;

  return (
    <div>
      <PostTable postList={rows} />
    </div>
  );
};

However, I encountered issues when trying to insert data. I initially wrote a code in the client component, but it resulted in the following error:
VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.

In response, I made modifications to my code as shown below:

Contact.jsx

"use client";

import React from "react";
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";

const Contact = () => {
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    const post = {
      name: e.target.name.value,
      password: e.target.password.value,
      phoneNumber: e.target.phoneNumber.value,
      email: e.target.email.value,
      title: e.target.title.value,
      content: e.target.content.value,
    };
    const JSONdata = JSON.stringify(post);
    const endpoint = "/api/send";

    try {
      const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSONdata,
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("response was not ok");
      }

      console.log("Post saved successfully");
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.json());
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("There was a problem saving the post:", error.message);
    }

    // ("use server");
    // await sql`
    //   INSERT INTO POSTS (TITLE, CONTENT, USER_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    //   VALUES (${post.title}, ${post.content}, ${post.name}, ${post.phoneNumber}, ${post.email}, ${post.password})
    // `;
  };
...
...


/api/send/route.js

import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";

export default async function savePost(req, res) {
  try {
    const { title, content, name, phoneNumber, email, password } = req.body;
    const result = await sql`
      INSERT INTO POSTS (TITLE, CONTENT, USER_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, EMAIL, PASSWORD)
      VALUES (${title}, ${content}, ${name}, ${phoneNumber}, ${email}, ${password})
    `;
    res.status(200).json({ result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error saving post:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Error saving post" });
  }
}

Unfortunately, this led to another error:
No HTTP methods exported in '/Users/user/Projects/mywebsite/src/app/api/send/route.js'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.
 POST /api/send 405 in 402ms

I believe I may not fully understand how serverless functions work. Can anyone provide assistance with this problem?
Thanks.

API route functions must be named strategically for each HTTP method, GET, POST, etc. (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#api-routes)
